# How to Draw This Workflow with Tikz Picture in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw the below picture in `tikz` and have attempted with the below `MWE`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, fatnode/.style={circle, fill=blue!20, minimum size=15mm}]
        \node[node] (A) at (0, 0) {Import};
        \node[node] (B) at (2, 0) {Tidy};
        \node[node] (C) at (4, 0) {Transform};
        \node[node] (D) at (6, 2) {Visualize};
        \node[node] (F) at (6, -2) {Model};
        \node[node] (G) at (8, 0) {Communicate};
        \draw [thick, ->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,above left] {};
        \draw [thick, ->] (B) -- (C) node[midway,above right] {};
        \draw [thick, ->] (C)  (D) to [bend right=20] node[midway,right] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have problems with the bend arrows and the shaded portion. I also want it in a curve-edged frame.

**Improved Trial**

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, fatnode/.style={circle, fill=blue!20, minimum size=15mm}]
        \node[node] (A) at (0, 0) {Import};
        \node[node] (B) at (2, 0) {Tidy};
        \node[node] (C) at (4, 0) {Transform};
        \node[node] (D) at (5.5, 0.4) {Visualize};
        \node[node] (F) at (5, -1) {Model};
        \node[node] (G) at (8, 0) {Communicate};
        \node[node] (H) at (6.5, 0) {};
        \draw [thick, ->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,above left] {};
        \draw [thick, ->] (B) -- (C) node[midway,above right] {};
        \draw [thick, ->] (H) -- (G) node[midway,above left] {};
        \draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|}}}] (C) to [bend left=45]  (D);
    \draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|}}}] (D) to [bend left=45]  (F);
        \draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|}}}] (F) to [bend left=45]  (C);{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>=Latex,thick]]
        \node (IMP) {Import};
        \node[right=of IMP] (TIDY) {Tidy};
        \node[right=of TIDY,cyan] (TRSFM) {Transform};
        \node[above right=0.5cm and 1cm of TRSFM,cyan] (VSL) {Visualize};
        \node[below right=0.5cm and 1cm  of TRSFM] (MDL) {Model};
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node[fit=(TRSFM)(VSL)(MDL),fill=cyan!20,rounded corners] (RCTL) {};
            \node[below right= 0pt and 2pt of RCTL.south west,cyan](EXPLR){\footnotesize Explore};
        \end{scope}
        \node[right=of RCTL] (CMCT) {Communicate};
        \begin{scope}
            \draw[->] (IMP) -- (TIDY);
            \draw[->] (TIDY) -- (TRSFM);
            \draw[->] (TRSFM.80) to[out=70,in=180] (VSL.180);
            \draw[->] (VSL.-70) to[out=-50,in=50] (MDL.50);
            \draw[->] (MDL.-170) to[out=-170,in=-80] (TRSFM.-80);
            \draw[->] (RCTL) -- (CMCT);
        \end{scope}
        \node[fit=(IMP)(RCTL)(EXPLR)(CMCT),rounded corners,draw]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Workflow fit backgrounds]

You can play with the `in` and `out` to adjust the arrows, or even try with Bezier curves.