# LatTeX Tikz: Make Different Colours(Text and Fill) for Different Nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to modify the attached `tikz` picture in the following ways:

- Make `Import`, `Tidy`, `Model`, `Communicate` to be of the same text and fill colour.
- Make `Transform` `Visualize` and `Explore to be of another text and fill colour.

Here is the `tikz` code that produces the picture:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, fatnode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size=0.0mm}, font=\sf,>=Latex,thick]
        \node[fatnode] (A) at (0, 0) {Import};
        \node[fatnode] (B) at (1.2, 0) {Tidy};
        \node[fatnode] (C) at (2.4, 0) {Transform};
        \node[fatnode] (D) at (3.8, 0.8) {Visualize};
        \node[fatnode] (E) at (3.8, -0.7) {Model};
        \node[node] (F) at (4.3, 0) {};
        \node[fatnode] (G) at (5.8, 0) {Communicate};
        \draw [thick, ->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,above left,] {};
        \draw [thick, ->] (B) -- (C) node[midway,above right] {};
        \draw [thick, ->] (F) -- (G) node[midway,above left] {};
        \draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|}}}] (C) to [bend left=45]  (D);
        \draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|}}}] (D) to [bend left=59]  (E);
        \draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|}}}] (E) to [bend left=45]  (C);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node [fill=blue!10, dotted, rounded corners, fit= (C) (D) (E) (F)] (H) {}; % enough to add two diagonal nodes
            \node[fill=white] at (H.south) {\footnotesize Explore};
            \node[draw,, rounded corners, fit=(A) (B) (C) (D) (E) (F) (G) (H)] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I actually started the journey [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602569/how-to-draw-this-workflow-with-tikz-picture-in-latex/602582#602582)

[image: My Tikz Picture]

Comment: Have you tried changing the code within the `fatnode/.style={....}`?  For example, what happens if you change it to `fatnode/.style={circle, draw=red,}`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an other style. In the code below, the `fill=white` modify the `fill=red!20` from `fatnode2`, since it is last.
I remove useless part of the original code and use relative positioning.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
    fatnode1/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size=0.0mm},
    fatnode2/.style={rectangle, draw=red, rounded corners, fill=red!20, minimum size=0.0mm},
    font=\sf,
    >=Latex,
    thick,
    node distance=1.2]
    \node[fatnode1] (A) at (0, 0) {Import};
    \node[fatnode1, right=of A] (B) {Tidy};
    \node[fatnode2, right=of B] (C) {Transform};
    \node[fatnode2, above right=of C] (D) {Visualize};
    \node[fatnode1, below right=of C] (E) {Model};
    \node [xshift=1.2cm, right=of C] (F) {};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [fill=blue!10, rounded corners, fit= (C) (D) (E) (F)] (H) {}; % enough to add two diagonal nodes
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \node[fatnode2, fill=white] (I) at (H.230) {\footnotesize Explore};
    \node[fatnode1, right=of H] (G) {Communicate};
    \draw [thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [thick, ->] (B) -- (C);
    \draw [thick, ->] (H) -- (G);
    \draw [->,thick] (C) to [bend left=45]  (D);
    \draw [->,thick] (D) to [bend left=59]  (E);
    \draw [->,thick] (E) to [bend left=45]  (C);
    \node[draw, rounded corners, fit=(A) (B) (C) (D) (E) (G) (H) (I)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]